# Path component of a CW-complex is a subcomplex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a CW-complex. I want to prove each of its path components contains a zero cell. For that, I want to prove that each of its components is again a CW-complex.

Please give me some hints.

Comment: I don't know at first hand whether in a CW-complex path-components coincide with components. What I do know is that components are always closed and that any closed set of a CW-complex is a sub-complex.

Comment: @drhab: This seems false to me, or at least I don't understand it in the usual sense of subcomplex. Consider $S^1$ represented as a CW complex with one 0-cell (at $(1, 0)$) and a single $1$-cell. The set $C = \{ (x, y) \in S^1 \mid x \le 0 \}$ is certainly a closed set, but not a subcomplex, in the sense that there's no subset of the cells of $S^1$ whose union is $C$.

Comment: @JohnHughes You are right. The theorem states: If $(X,\mathcal E)$ is a CW-complex, $\mathcal E'\subseteq\mathcal E$ **and** $X'=\cup\mathcal E'$ then $(X',\mathcal E')$ is a subcomplex iff $X'$ is closed. I overlooked the extra condition on $X'$. Here $\mathcal E$ denotes the collection of cells.

Comment: @drhab Ah...thanks. I was thinking that you might be thinking of some theorem like "there's a subdivision of the original CW complex such that $C$ is a subcomplex," but that seemed as if it might be *very* hard to prove. :)  Indeed, I'm not even sure how I'd define "subdivision". :)

Answer (score 2):

A subcomplex of a CW-complex $X$ is a subspace $A  \subset X$ which is a union of closed cells of $X$. Recall that a closed $n$-cell $e^n_\alpha$ is the image of an attaching map $\phi^n_\alpha : D^n  \to X^{n-1}$ defined on the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, each $e^n_\alpha$ is pathwise connected. Note that if $e^n_\alpha \subset A$, then also all $e^m_\beta$ such that $\mathring{e}^m_\beta \cap e^n_\alpha \ne \emptyset$ must be contained in $A$. Here $\mathring{e}^m_\beta$ denotes the open cell associated to $e^m_\beta$, i.e. the set $\phi^m_\beta(\mathring{D}^m) \subset e^m_\beta$. $\mathring{D}^m$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Each path component $P$ of $X$ is a union of closed cells: If $e^n_\alpha \cap P \ne \emptyset$, then $e^n_\alpha \cup P$ is pathwise connected so that $e^n_\alpha \subset e^n_\alpha \cup P \subset P$.

Comment: I don't understand the "Note" comment. For every point $p \in P$ could I take a certain cell of $X$ which contains $p$ and from that arguing that since $e_\alpha^n \cap P \ne \varnothing$ then $e_\alpha^n \subset P?$

Comment: @jacopoburelli Frankly, I cannot remember why I added the part beginning with "Note". It is true, but we do not need it to prove that $P$ is a union of closed cells. You can do it as in your comment or as in my answer (partition $X$ in closed cells disjoint from $P$ and in closed cells intersecting $P$; the latter must be contained in $P$).

Comment: Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Let C be your pathcomponent, and take any cell $e_n\to C$, which is, say, of dimension $n$. Then the boundary of $e_n$ maps to a cell of dimension ___?